# Is this a valid Busy Beaver lower bound and does it help?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I was struck by a comment someone made about the recent BB(748) ZFC-independence result being shortened to BB(745) pointing out that while this reduced the number of TM states by only 3 it reduced the value of BB(n) by a really big factor.

Given that we have a few values and estimates for discrete BB(n) values (Defining BB to be the shift-count function here but I'm not sure that matters)...

$BB(1)=1, BB(2)=6, BB(3)=21, BB(4)=107, BB(5)\ge47,176,870\;\;\text{and}\;\;BB(6)>10\uparrow\uparrow15$

Can we say (with any confidence) the following?

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{BB(n)}{BB(n-1)}=\infty$

...and...

$\forall{n\ge3}:\;\;\frac{BB(n+1)}{BB(n)}>\frac{BB(n)}{BB(n-1)}$

Or might there be moderately (for BB) relatively flat plateaus interspersed between effectively vertical cliffs? BB(2) = 6BB(1)  but BB(3) is only $\frac{21}{6}$BB(2); after this normal service seems to be resumed.

Comment: You are wrong about $BB(5)$ -- what we know is that $BB(5)\ge 47,176,870$. And [we are pretty sure](https://bbchallenge.org/story) that in fact $BB(5)=47,176,870$.

Comment: And perhaps you meant your first limit to be $\infty$, not $0$?

Comment: @TonyK I did indeed.  Thank you.